# How to copy the content of an aux file to another aux file?

Tags: auxiliary-files

I have two aux files attached to my LaTeX document : aux_1 and aux_2.
I would like, at some point, to copy the content of aux_1 to aux_2.

More precisely, the file aux_1 does already contain some text. I want to copy the content of aux_2 after the already existing text.

Is it possible to do it ? I use the `newfile` package to deal with the aux files.

PS : *If possible*, I would like a LaTeX-friendly answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\write18{cp aux_1 aux_2}
```

(On Windows, use `copy` instead, I think.)

Comment: `\immediate\write18` if the command needs to be performed at a precise moment; without `\immediate` it will be deferred to the next shipout operation (that might never happen).

Comment: @egreg: Good advice, though that makes my answer more serious than I intended it.  I'm just pushing my "why do that in LaTeX when you have a perfectly good OS instead" angle on excessive TeX programming.

Comment: I suspect that your proposition will overwrite aux_1 to aux_2.

Comment: @Colas: Yes, it will.  You can use a different operating system utility that will append them, e.g. `cat`, if you want that.  As I said, my point is that this is not a TeX task and the solution is to use `\write18` to farm it out to the system.

Comment: Thanks ! I understand that I do strange things, sorry about that :)